# Background image isn't visible in the viewport

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

[image: here's the image in case if it's the picture]

Is the problem with the picture or something else?
I'm trying to put a image to Blender's viewport but its not showing. I tried pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Numpad1</kbd> but it just made the default shape rounder.
I'm using blender 2.78.

Answer (score 3):

Use the <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> to enter preset ortho view. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> from the top of your keyboard adds a Subdivision Surface modifier.